# How to put a variable into pygame key detector?

Tags: python, variables, pygame, insert

I'm making a function that will wait for the user to press a key. Is there a simple way where I can set a variable to a key I want pressed and then have the computer wait for that key?

```
wait_for_key("SPACE")
```

Above is me calling the function.

```
def wait_for_key(key):
    pressed=0
    while pressed==0:
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_key]:
            pressed=1
```

But here, the computer doesn't recognize K_key. I tried using brackets, and even the .format method but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.event.get()` will not work if you don't handle the events in the loop. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

```py
def wait_for_key(key):
    pressed=0
    while pressed==0:
    
        pygame.event.pump()
    
        # [...]
```

---

If you want to wait kor <kbd>SPACE</kbd> you have to pass the key `pygame.K_SPACE` to `wait_for_key` (see [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)). Test the state of argument `key`:

```py
wait_for_key(pygame.K_SPACE)
```

```py
def wait_for_key(key):
    pressed=0
    while pressed==0:
        pygame.event.pump()
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[key]:
            pressed=1
```

---

However, if you just want to get if a key is pressed,  you can use the `KEYDOWN` event (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)):

```py
def wait_for_key(key):
    pressed=0
    while pressed==0:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == key: 
                    pressed = 1
```

---

[`pygame.key.name()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.name) returns the name of a key identifier. Use it if you want to pass the name of a key to the function `wait_for_key`:

```py
wait_for_key("space")
```

```py
def wait_for_key(key_name):
    pressed=0
    while pressed==0:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.key.name(event.key) == key_name: 
                    pressed = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and string formatting to do this:

```
key = "SPACE"

>>> getattr(pygame, f"K_{key}")
32
```